# How do I count attendance in Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I want to make an attendance sheet in excel. If a child is present, the teacher will write `P` in a cell, or `A` for absent, or `L` for latecomer. I want to get the number of `P` or `L` in a range to calculate total number of days in a month for each child, where the child has been either present or late.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you have a worksheet in this format:

```
+---+------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|   |     A      |      B      |      C      |      D      |      E      |
+---+------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
|   | Student    | Day 1       | Day 2       | Day 3       | Days present|
| 1 | Joe        | A           | P           | P           | 2           |
| 2 | Frank      | P           | P           | P           | 3           |
| 3 | Sally      | P           | A           | A           | 1           |
+---+------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

Then you can use the COUNTIF function, eg:

```
=COUNTIF(B2:D2,"P")
```

To count instances of both P and L, use two count functions and add the results together:

```
=COUNTIF(B2:D2,"P")+COUNTIF(B2:D2,"L")
```

Comment: No problem. If this answer was correct, please accept it as the correct answer so it is marked as solved. Thanks!

Comment: I have to add l(which indicate late comer) also with attendance.So 'P' and 'l' also counted in total days present.Kindly help me in this.

Comment: In the next column across, use the same formula but with a l instead of P: `=COUNTIF(B2:D2,"l")`

Comment: is there any formula which will count both p and l?

Comment: Hi @teacher, I have updated my answer to meet your revised requirements. I have also updated your question.